# Editing the Synaptics touchpad driver registry settings

Tags: windows-7, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

Running the latest version of the Synaptics touchpad driver (17.0.19)

I'm also running mDesktop, which gives virtual desktop functionality. At the moment I have it set up so that "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>" and "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>" switch between the desktops.

I would like to set up the three-finger swipe on the touchpad do let me switch. I'm thinking that I can put a key into the AppProfiles key for the Synaptics driver for Windows Explorer to accomplish this, but I'm sure what the specific DWORD values I should use are. Where can I find them?